# Why does Proc#binding show a variable is defined when defined? does not

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

This question deals with Ruby 1.9.3 specifically:

```
p defined?(a)
p binding.eval "defined?(a)"
b = lambda { |x| x }
p b.binding.eval "defined?(a)" # This prints "local-variable"
p defined?(a) # This prints nil!
a = 2
p defined?(a)
p b.binding.eval "defined?(a)"
```

What confuses me is line four.  I'm not sure why this prints "local-variable" rather than nil.  This seems to imply that lambda is somehow "looking farther."  (I figure `defined?` being an operator has something to do with this.)

Also, although the binding says that it is defined, attempting to use it like so:

```
p b.binding.eval "a"
```

*before* the assignment on line 6 results in a NameError.

EDIT:
I have tested this on

- 1.9.3-362
- 1.9.3-374
- 2.0.0-preview2

I get the same behavior in all of the cases.

Comment: What is the specific version of Ruby you are using (include the patch level)? I cannot replicate this on 1.9.3-p374.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: 1.9.3-p362.  However, I can replicate this behavior in 374 and in the latest 2.0.0 preview.  (Let me again emphasize this only works using the batch interpreter, it does not work interactively as parsing the REPL works differently)

Comment: Can you define “batch interpreter”? Running `->(o) { o }.binding.eval('defined? a')` in IRB, Pry, and Ruby directly all give me `nil`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall running it via `ruby file.rb`

Comment: Wait, I can replicate it. I think I know what’s going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that just calling `defined?` happens at parse-time, and since no variable `a` exists yet, it returns `nil` as expected. However, when you `eval` the `defined?` call, it’s deferred to runtime. But `defined?` is still lexically scoped, and since the entire file has already been parsed and compiled, the variable `a` *does* exist, because it was created at parse-time, which is now complete.

We can show this in a simplified example:

```
defined? a         #=> nil
eval 'defined? a'  #=> "local-variable"
a = 2
defined? a         #=> "local-variable"
```

But if we don’t define `a` at all:

```
defined? a         #=> nil
eval 'defined? a'  #=> nil
```

As you can see, it doesn’t have anything to do with `binding`, and instead simply has to do with `eval` deferring the evaluation of the `defined?` till after the entire file has been parsed.

Comment: yep, *defined?* is not a method but an operator. another of ruby's hitches.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually line six that is the source of the mystery.  Ruby creates objects in conditionals even when the code is not executed.  If a variable is assigned, it is implicitly declared.  [This blog post has a quick explanation](http://ramenlabs.com/2010/02/26/rubys-surprising-handling-of-local-variables/)

I found this a little surprising myself.  As for your code, in a new IRB session, you should see 'nil' as the output of line four, but if you run the code more than once, your variable is already there (in the form of a Nil object) and you'll get the perplexing news that a local variable exists.  YMMV.

Comment: that's not really it though.  I knew that Ruby had the `if` behavior, and my question didn't really deal with that (what I'm talking about happens in the `ruby` interpreter only, `irb` will parse differently).  I removed the `if` to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature of Ruby source parser. If there does exist variable assignment in Ruby source code it's initialized to nil (so it gets defined) even if never called during program's execution.
There is the assignment on line 6 to the local variable *a* (`a = 2`). It does not matter it is defined *after* your assignment on line 3 as it gets initialized to nil by ruby parser before a source is even executed. As lambda does not introduce a new scope, it *knows* about *a* variable so you get unsurprisingly "local-variable" result (a == nil).
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021477/in-ruby-why-after-starting-irb-foo-nil-says-undefined-error-and-foo-nil-gi#4023224) for some details.

The different behaviour between running in irb or passing to ruby interpreter is directly related to the above paragraph. irb evaluates expressions line-by-line (REPL), ruby parses the whole source before its execution.

Comment: I understand Ruby's parsing this in this manner, but that still doesn't answer my question: if that's the case then why the mismatch between the lambda's binding and just using defined on size 5 and 6.  Those two have the same scope (since binding will just capture the scope at the time the lambda was created).  I don't understand the mismatch, can you explain?